# How do I correct Error: String[] is not initialized

Tags: java

I have a method named getNext() that reads a line of text from the file, splits the line into tokens,
and returns an array containing the tokens (strings) from the line that was split.

The error message I'm having is: "The local variable lineSplit may not have been initialized"

```
public String[] getNext() {
    String line;
    String[] lineSplit;

    try {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            lineSplit = line.split(Character.toString(delimiter));
        }
    } catch (IOException error) {
        System.out.println("IO EXCEPTION");
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lineSplit;
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If `br` is already at end of file then the loop will execute zero times and `lineSplit` will never be assigned a value. What do you want it to return in that case?

Comment: Thats fine if it doesn't get run in that instance. I just want help with the code presented. @DavidConrad

Comment: *"How do I correct Error: String[] is not initialized"* Initialize it!

Comment: David was trying to explain the problem to you.  If your BufferedReader has no lines to read, `lineSplit` will never be initialized, because the body of your `while` loop will not run even once.  So it is possible for the method to run without ever initializing `lineSplit`, which means you don’t have a value to return in that case.

Comment: @JoWhite That's not fine, it's an error, which is why your code does not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize lineSplit with a default value to be returned in case the BufferedReader has no more lines to read or an IOException is thrown, in which case your current code would try to return a variable that hasn't been initialized: this is the root cause of the error. Setting it to null at the start seems appropriate.

```
String[] lineSplit = null;
```

Comment: It's not at all clear that returning `null` is okay here. This will make the code *compile* but make also make it do the ***wrong thing***.

Comment: @DavidConrad From the name, it seems that the method is supposed to return a String array of the next line split by the delimiter. In the absence of any more lines to read, `null` seems to be the most appropriate return value; in fact, [BufferedReader#readLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) also returns `null` if the end of the stream has been reached, so this method could also be used in a similar fashion.

Comment: In order to know if it's an appropriate return value, we'd have to see the caller, but I suppose OP can deal with that.

Comment: @DavidConrad Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "*The local variable lineSplit may not have been initialized*" is clear enough no? You have to initialize the String `lineSplit` giving to it an adequate dimension e.g. `String[] lineSplit = new String[1000];`